# when i write a special char in the text area (like < > & /) it ignores the rest of the code

Tags: forms, servlets, jakarta-ee

This is my form code and the servlet, when i write a special char in the `textarea` (like < > & /) it ignores the rest of the code

Below is my form code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Soumettre un code script</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Soumettre un code script</H1>
<FORM ACTION="CodePreviewGood" METHOD="POST">
 Code:<BR>
 <TEXTAREA ROWS="6" COLS="40" NAME="code"></TEXTAREA><BR/><BR/>
 <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Envoyer votre Code">&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Tout effacer">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and that's my servlet code

```
package pkg;


import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CodePreviewGood
 */
@WebServlet("/CodePreviewGood")
public class CodePreviewGood extends HttpServlet {
     @Override
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     String title = "Code Sample";
     String docType =
     "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n";
     out.println(docType +
     "<HTML>\n" +
     "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
     "<BODY>\n" +
     "<H1>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
     "<PRE>\n" +
     getCode(request) +
     "</PRE>\n" +
     "Alors, Comment trouvez-vous ce script : masscré ou préservé?\n" +
     "</BODY></HTML>");
     }
     protected String getCode(HttpServletRequest request) {
     return(request.getParameter("code"));
     }
    }
```

'''

could you please help me to find a solution.
thank you.

Comment: write `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in your `doPost()` method of servlet and sees if that works.

Comment: its not working